# Matrix Subtotal is coming wrong in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have three measures as follows :

```
TSMGLOBAL = CALCULATE(SUMX(Savings,[sum(Risk Percentage*USLP Savings)])/1000000,FILTER(ALL(Savings),Savings[ICB]="YES"&&Savings[Scenario]="YTD" && Savings[Strategic Pillar]="TSM initiative"))

TSMLOCAL = CALCULATE(SUMX(Savings,[sum(Risk Percentage*USLP Savings)])/1000000,FILTER(ALL(Savings),Savings[ICB]="NO"&&Savings[Scenario]="YTD" && Savings[Strategic Pillar]="TSM initiative"))

#finalsavingsTSMSUMX = 
IF(CONTAINS(Savings,Savings[Location - Region (L1)],"Global"),[#SUMXSavingsTSMGlobal],[#SUMXSavingsTSMLocal])
```

The thing is, when I am putting this in my Matrix Visual , the Subtotal Column (which is directly coming from the matrix itself, it is not created by me) is taking the value of **GLOBAL** Measure (TSMGLOBAL) and not actually calculating the subtotal which it should be. I am trying to figure out why is this happening. Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of struggle, I finally came up with a solution and a reason as to why this was happening.

Since a measure was already used with a filter of region as Global , measure 3 was acting up due to application of same filter.

Instead I simply put

```
#finalTSMSavings = TSM Global Measure + TSM Local Measure
```

And it started working. :)
Hope this helps someone trying the same solution. I would love to know some other approach as well.